# What is the equivalent of "susceptibility" in medical literature, but to a healthy condition?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, semantics, medical

In medical literature the word `susceptibility` collocates with negative adjectives or nouns -- negative prosody. Likewise, the word `predisposing` factors or state is mostly associated with negative nouns: cancer, disease, and so forth.

I want similar words, but for a healthy condition or a healthy phenomenon that *can* take place in *some* individuals after acquiring certain infection, let's call this phenomenon `H`. There is individual variation in displaying this healthy phenomenon.

so similar to below sentences, but in the context of health rather than disease:

> Some individuals are more susceptible to develop H in their stomach.
>
> Only subjects with a predisposing state will develop the H phenomenon.
>
> These factors are most likely to be responsible for having the susceptibility to H in some individuals.

Comment: People are not susceptible positively or negatively to good health. They either have it or they don't. There is not a median from which some are susceptible to illness and others are "H" to better health. Good health is the *absence* of *disease or other limiting conditions*. Lucky people have good genes which may protect them from a host of illnesses we less genetically fortunate people suffer from. The best we can do is to work on increasing our health and limiting, modifying, or eradicating disease.

Comment: I am afraid that we are not on the same page. I clarified the point more.

Comment: not really. To reiterate, some people when they get this infection they acquire immunity or this H, some don't.

Comment: consider *E.coli*, without it your body have limited access to vitamin K, but let us imagine that it can only happen with some people -- lucky -- but we can't write `lucky` in the literature, what other word can be more fitting? privilege or what?

Comment: doctorate, I saw your point early on. Will post the right word as soon as it rolls from the tip of my tongue. (If someone doesn't come up with it sooner, that is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the concept in a slightly different way (the OP's example sentences will need rephrasing),

***[conducive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conducive)***

> adjective (usually **conducive** to) making a certain situation or outcome likely or possible.
>   *the harsh lights and cameras were hardly conducive to a relaxed atmosphere*

syn: *contribute to, lead to, tend to promote, make for, facilitate, favour, aid, assist, help, benefit, encourage*

> Some individuals' constitutions are more **conducive to** developing H in their stomach.
>   Only a predisposing state in the subjects can be **conducive to** developing the H phenomenon.
>   These factors are most likely to be responsible for a **conduciveness to** H in some individuals.

[*meta*:] This is just an interim suggestion. Will edit in a better alternative when I find one.

Comment: +1,pls make sure to rephrase my 3 sentences above, with whatever word you would prefer, there is hope.

Comment: "conducive to developing good health" got 1 hit (a nonsense hit), "conducive to developing health/healthy" got 17 hits, half of them preceded by *not*. I like your idea - conducive/facilitates/etc., but... it doesn't make sense in this application.

Comment: Wait for more hits ;)

Comment: is it possible to say: people with *favorable* background will develop the `H` phenomenon.

Comment: In the given domain, *develop* too is more commonly used with a negative condition: cf. *develop ulcers*

Comment: then may be `acquire`, `attain`, `own`, `bring forth`, `generate`?

Comment: @Kris I disagree about the use of develop in only negative contexts within medical literature c.f. phrases like, _"following inoculation with X the subject was observed to develop immunity to Y after 2 weeks."_

Comment: "Conducive to good health" garners 128,000 Google hits at my time/location; "conducive to health" yields 2,730,000 Google hits.